# Qt - Repeatedly write at beginning of file

Tags: c++, qt

How do I write a new line to the beginning of a QTextstream?

I am tracing a binary tree backwards and writing the result to a log-file. I want the root-node to be the first line on the list. Simply appending lines leads to a reverse order. What I need to do is to add the new line at the top of the file.

Here is a simplified example of what I have got:

```
QFile mFile("fileName.csv");
QTextStream out(&mFile);
if (!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
        qDebug() << " Could not open foundPath file";
        return;
}

int cursor = 10;
while (cursor > 0){
    out << cursor << "\n";
    cursor--;
}
```

The result is obviously 10, 9, ... , 1, but I want 1, 2, ..., 10.

Comment: What about inverting that loop or using a stack? Alternatively if you don't know all the lines in advance just read the entire file, write the new line and append the contents.

Comment: I like the Qstack idea. I do now all the lines in advance (the file is empty before), so I am going to use this. I assume it is in general a better idea of using a stack of string rather than just a single big string?

Comment: I suppose a single big string would trigger multiple reallocations and copies around. A single container with a LIFO order should yield better performances.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overwrite the "first line", because files aren't stored line-wise, but as bytes after bytes; there's nothing special about a line break. So if you replace the first line of a file by a line that's longer, you will overwrite parts of the second line, for example.

You *could* read in the whole file, and prepend the first line before re-writing the rest, but that is going to be very slow and ressource intense once your log file gets bigger.

The right approach would obviously be to reverse the display, not the log.

Comment: I know all the elements I need to write before, so I will go with Marco's idea to push the lines into a stack first.